I am getting SQLSTATE[42S22] error after running the setup:upgrade command after importing a dump file in mysql
i have tried reindexing and toggling from schedule to realtime mode and i am still getting the error. This is what i get after php bin/magento setup:upgrade
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'NEW', query was: CREATE TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_p
roduct_entity_int FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_category_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cataloginventory_stock_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END


importing means you imported entire database? If yes then, your sql file missing something.
